# Rails active admin undefined methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, activeadmin

I'm using this code:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Dashboard" do

    section "Recent Posts" do 
        table_for Post.order("id desc").limit(15) do
            column :id
            column "Post title", :title do |post|   
                link_to post.title,[:admin,post]
            end
            column :category,sortable: :category
            column :created_at
        end
        strong (link_to "Show all posts")
    end
end
```

and I get this error:

```
undefined method `section'
```

if I delete 'section' do-end part, then I get error for:

```
undefined method `table_for'
```

and so on...

Seems like I cant use any of active admin given methods, maybe I'm mising something? Any gems or something? I installed active admin gem using this setup:

```
gem 'inherited_resources', github: 'activeadmin/inherited_resources'
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
gem 'devise', github: 'plataformatec/devise'
```

I'm using rails 5

Comment: I am getting same error in partial for `panel` method

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I managed to transform my code and now it compiles without any errors.

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Dashboard" do
  content :title => proc{ I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard") } do
    columns do
      column do
        panel "Recent Posts" do
          table_for Post.order("id desc").limit(5) do
            column :name do |post|
              link_to post.title, [:admin, post]
            end
            column :created_at
          end
          strong (link_to "Show All Posts" , :posts )
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I suppose my previously used syntax is old and not supported any more.

Comment: I think actually wrapping the everything in the content block did the trick. There was nothing wrong with your syntax per se.  See custom pages in AA here: https://activeadmin.info/10-custom-pages.html#create-a-new-page

Comment: any idea how we can solve this for `panel` method to use in partials?